# Не могу получить результат выполнения цикла с условием внутри

Tags: javascript, if, for, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Здравствуйте нужна помощь.
Смотрите проблема такая. Мне нужно найти имя которое соответствует емейлу вошедшего. Я его нашел без проблем и получил в переменную "namemail" результат с помощью: (ФРАГМЕНТ СЦЕНАРИЯ)

```
        var oklist1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Контроль");
        var list2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Работники/данные/списки");
        var range1 = oklist1.getRange(3,4,18,1).getValues();
        var range2;
        var date = new Date;
        var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
        var mlist2 = list2.getRange("D:D").getValues();
        var demg = oklist1.getRange("D:D").getValues();
        var maillist2;
        for(var i=0;i<mlist2.length;i++){
          if(mlist2[i].indexOf(email)!==-1){
            maillist2=i+1;
            var namemail = list2.getRange(maillist2,2).getValues();
          }
        }
```

Дальше по логике моего задания мне нужно проверить внесено ли это имя уже или еще нет?! но на другом листе и я пишу следующую часть сценария: (ФРАГМЕНТ СЦЕНАРИЯ)

```
var ressul;
      for(var b=0;b<demg.length;b++){
        if(demg[i]==namemail) {
          ressul= b+1;
          Logger.log(ressul);
        }
      }
```

И я не получаю никакого никакого результата в журнал, кроме "
Примечание  Выполнение начато.
Примечание  Выполнение завершено."
А если вместо "namemail" пишу конкретное имя, ну типа:

```
        for(var b=0;b<demg.length;b++){
          if(demg[b]=="Дмитрий") {
            ressul= b+1;
            Logger.log(ressul);
          }
        }
```

То получаю результат. Помогите пожалуйста найти проблему, что это может быть? Мне нужно чтобы применялось именно "namemail".

Даю полный сценарий:

```
      function timeDay() {
      var oklist1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Контроль");
      var list2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Работники/данные/списки");
      var range1 = oklist1.getRange(3,4,18,1).getValues();
      var range2;
        var date = new Date;
         var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
          var mlist2 = list2.getRange("D:D").getValues();
        var demg = oklist1.getRange("D:D").getValues();
          var maillist2;
           for(var i=0;i<mlist2.length;i++){
             if(mlist2[i].indexOf(email)!==-1){
               maillist2=i+1;
               var namemail = list2.getRange(maillist2,2).getValues();
               }
             }

            var ressul;
          for(var b=0;b<demg.length;b++){
          if(demg[i]==namemail) {
          ressul= b+1;
          Logger.log(ressul);
           }
          }
        }
```

Comment: А если сразу после строчки `var namemail = ...` добавить `Logger.log(namemail);`, то выводится ожидаемое значение или что-то не то?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Да, если после 'var namemail =list2.getRange(maillist2,2).getValues()' добавить 'Logger.log(namemail);' то я получаю нужный результат, но в условии след. цикла почему-то не могу его использовать.

Comment: А если в последнем цикле в каждой итерации перед проверкой условия выводить в лог значения `demg[i]` и `namemail`, может, что-то прояснится?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty
'for(var b=0;b<demg.length;b++){
Logger.log(namemail);
 if(demg[b]==namemail)' В этом случае я получаю просто одно и тоже имя которое соответствует почте. до конца диапазона

Answer (score 1):

проблема решена. нужно было вместо :

```
    if(demg[i]==namemail) записать так: if(namemail==demg[i][0])
```